# Python plt.contour colorbar

Tags: python, plot, fft, contour

I am trying to do a plot of a seismic wave using plt.contour.
I have 3 arrays:

- time (x-axis)
- frequency (y-axis)
- amplitude (z-axis)

This is my results so far:
[image: plot of the function using plt.contour]

The problem is that I want to change the scaling of the colorbar: making a gradation and not having this white color when the amplitude is low. But I am not able to do so, even though I spent a lot of time browsing the doc.

I read that `plt.pcolormesh` is not appropriate here (it is just working here because I am in a special case), but this what I want to get regarding to the colours and colorbar:

[image: plot using plt.pcolormesh]

This is the code I wrote:

```
T         = len(time[0])*(time[0][1] - time[0][0])  # multiply ampFFT with T to offset
Z         = abs(ampFFT)*(T)                         # abbreviation

# freq = frequency, ampFFT = Fast Fourier Transform of the amplitude of the wave
# freq, amFFT and time have same dimensions: 40 x 1418 (40 steps of time discretization x steps to have the total time. 2D because it is easier to use) 

maxFreq   = abs(freq).max()                            # maxium frequency for plot boundaries
maxAmpFFT = abs(Z).max()/2                             # maxium ampFFT for plot boundaries of colorbar divided by 2 to scale better with the colors
minAmpFFT = abs(Z).min()

plt.figure(1)
plt.contour(time, freq, Z, vmin=minAmpFFT, vmax=maxAmpFFT)
plt.colorbar()

plt.ylim(0,maxFreq)                                    # 0 to remove the negative frequencies useless here
plt.title("Amplitude intensity regarding to time and frequency")
plt.xlabel('time (in secondes)')
plt.ylabel('frequency (in Hz)')

plt.show()
```

Thank you for your attention!

NB : In case you were wondering about `plt.pcolormesh`: the plot is completely messed up when I choose to increase the time discretization (here I split the time in 40, but when I split the time in 1000 the plot is not correct, and I want to be able to split the time in smaller pieces).

**EDIT:** When I use `plt.contourf` instead of `plt.contour` I got this plot:
[image: plot with plt.contourf] 
Which is not really convincing either. I understand why the yellow colour takes so much space (it is because I set a low vmax), but I don't understand why there is still white colour in my plot.

**EDIT 2:** My teacher plotted my data, and I have the correct data. The only problem that is left is the white background in my plot (and the deep blue on left and right border for nor apparent reason when I use `plt.contourf`). Despite those problems, the highest amplitude is located around 0.5 Hz, which is in agreement with the work of my teacher.
He used gnuplot, but since I don't know gnuplot, I prefer to use python.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this line? T         = len(time[0])*(time[0][1] - time[0][0])

Comment: additionally what do temps and freq look like, they will be the x and y conordinates for the contours.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. this line is to calculate the offset. When I split my time array and do the FFT, the amplitude of the signal decrease. This line is used to correct this effect. time[i] is always the same size, so as (time[i][j+1] - time[i][j]), therefore I chose arbitrary index numbers.

Comment: temps is time, sorry for the typo (I updated my post), I wanted to translate the variables name. They both have the same dimensions.   time range from 1960.15 to 10521.51 sec (because the wave does not occurs at the beginning in the data).
freq range from -3.312 to 3.307, but it does not increase like time (sometimes the value increase, sometimes they decrease, etc). Should I sort my freq array before plotting ?

Comment: Instinct says no remember it providing the 'y' coordinants so matplotlib will take pairs from temps and freq to plot.One other point are you sure it is a contour plot you want? Your example looks more like a bar plot...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not wrote it here, but before plotting, I built a loop to check that for every iteration, for every i, (time[i][j+1] - time[i][j]) is always the same size, and len(time[i]) is the same size as len(freq) and len(ampFFT). Unfortunately, I have to use something like `plt.contourf` because I in my internship, this is how seismogram are made.  
I'm back, talked with my teacher. He used gnuplot to check that my data were correct (he gave me data he already worked on). The data I have are correct, so it is definitely how I plot my data that cause the problem.

Comment: Understood. Ok here's what I think you need to achieve: the x and y coordinates (temps and freq) have describe boxes! This is not going to be so easy. For each freq you are going to need a 'left' and 'right' temp and for each temp you are going to need an 'upper' and 'lower' freq...

Comment: looking again at your exa mple it seems like there is a 'delta' on  time axis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just found an easier way, a workaround: use a 3D plot with mplot3d and set the matplotlib view to be normal to the x-y plane (view from above).  
(I will update my post to show the code I implemented).

Answer (score 0):

### **Solution/Workaround I found**

Here is what I did to display my data like `countourf` does, but without the display problems:
**Explanation**: for the surface, I took `abs(freq)` instead of just `freq` because I have negative frequencies.
It is because that when calculating the frequency of a FFT, you have a frequency that repeat itself a 2nd time like this:
[image: example of frequency]

**You have 2 way of obtaining this frequency:**
 - **the frequency is positive**, this array is 2 x Nyquist frequency (so if you divide the array by 2, you have all your wave, and it doesn't repeat itself).
 - **the frequency starts negative and go to positive**, this array also is 2 x Nyquist frequency (so if you remove the negative value you have all your wave, and it doesn't repeat itself).

**Python `fft.fftfreq` use the 2nd option.** `plot_surface` doesn't work well with removing the data of an array (for me it was still displayed). So I made the frequency value absolute and the problem disappeared.

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(18,15))    # figsize: increase plot size
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(time, abs(freq), Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.magma, linewidth=0, antialiased=False, vmin=minAmpFFT, vmax=maxAmpFFT)

ax.set_zlim(0, maxAmpFFT)
ax.set_ylim(0, maxFreq)

ax.view_init(azim=90, elev=90)          # change view to top view, with axis in the right direction

plt.title("Amplitude intensity (m/Hz^0.5) regarding to time and frequency")
plt.xlabel('x : time (in secondes)')
plt.ylabel('y : frequency (in Hz)')

# ax.yaxis._set_scale('log')            # should be in log, but does not work 


plt.gca().invert_xaxis()                # invert x axis !! MUST BE AFTER X,Y,Z LIM
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()                # invert y axis !! MUST BE AFTER X,Y,Z LIM

plt.colorbar(surf)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is the plot I got:

[image: 3D plot]